# Need some help leveraging %{HTTP_REFERER} in apache

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a use case wherein, if request Request URI starts with `/<path-info>(.*)` the redirect the user to `/fr-fr/404.hml`. And the initial request has the referrer like `https://{host}/fr-fr/home.html`. I have the following configuration to handle the use case,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/<path-info>(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^/(.*)/(.*).html(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/404.html
```

However, during testing I figured the `{HTTP_REFERER}` is not worked as I intended.
I have tested my configuration using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. Can someone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was expecting ```%{HTTP_REFERER}``` would contain referrer's the path information. From which I could obtain the ```fr-fr```.  As our intention is redirect, language specific redirects.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the use case. The language code REQUEST_URI is not accurate. As, it's not a valid anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/abc/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^.]+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/404.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

`HTTP_REFERER` contains full URL i.e. `scheme:host/uri`.

I am keeping `R=302` for testing purpose. Once you've tested it, change it to `R=301` to make it permanent redirect.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. However, I don't see this working yet. https://ibb.co/X52ffM9

Comment: See my edit. Just copy/paste rule **as is** and test.

Comment: No Anubhava. This did not work as well. https://ibb.co/20zYZnV

Comment: Are you testing it on some online tester instead of your Apache?

Comment: I was indeed testing  in an online tester. However, I have this tested in apache. I see the condition has met but the redirect is RewriteRule isn't working as expected. The page is redirected to ```https://{host}/{host}/404.html```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227904/discussion-between-phemanthkumar28-and-anubhava).